# Error: Expected resource of type anim [ResourceType] Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I cannot generate a signed apk

G:\Projects\Apps\Plus\app\src\main\java\com\bork\cleaner\ui\RubbishCleanActivity.java
Error: Expected resource of type anim [ResourceType]

RubbishCleanActivity.java File

```
public void onClickClear() {
    getActionBar().hide();
    this.layoutContainer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.layoutContainer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.mContext, R.anim.rote_anim);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            RubbishCleanActivity.this.doneRocket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RubbishCleanActivity.this.doneImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_white_128dp_2x);
            imageRush.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RubbishCleanActivity.this.doneBtn.setVisibility(0);
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    this.doneRocket.setAnimation(anim);
    if (this.mCleanerService != null && !this.mCleanerService.isScanning() && !this.mCleanerService.isCleaning() && this.mCleanerService.getCacheSize() > 0) {
        this.mAlreadyCleaned = false;
        this.mCleanerService.cleanCache();
    }
}

@TargetApi(19)
private void setTranslucentStatus(boolean on) {
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= 67108864;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= -67108865;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}

private boolean isProgressBarVisible() {
    return this.mProgressBar.getVisibility() == 0;
}

private void showProgressBar(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        this.mProgressBar.setVisibility(0);
        return;
    }
    this.mProgressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.mContext, 17432577));
    this.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

thanks for helping